# aria-pressed placement in Bootstrap accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, wai-aria

Is this where aria-pressed is supposed to be in a Bootstrap accordion? Why doesn't the state change when I open the tab?

```
                  <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThis">
                        <h6 class="panel-title">
                          <button class="accordion-toggle" type="button" role="button" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="1">Panel Heading</button>
                        </h6>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseThis" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <ul>
                              <li class="nice-link" data-filter=".one"><a href="#" tabindex="1">One</a></li>
                              <li class="nice-link" data-filter=".two"><a href="#" tabindex="2">Two</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: From the W3C (the people who made the ARIA spec): https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use aria-expanded, not pressed, to indicate whether an accordion was opened or closed.

You should check your code vs the examples shown on the bootstraps documentation site. They clearly lay out how to set up accordions and it would help alleviate additional red flags with your code (tabindexes on elements that don't need/shouldn't have tab indexes, role of button on a button element)

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code to make toggle button
```

[Here you find how to define aria-pressed in button using span tag[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW06a.jpg)

```
<span tabindex="0"
    role="button"
    id="toggle"
    aria-presed="false">
    Mute
</span>
```